# Dropbox doesn't autostart in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, startup, dropbox

I have installed Dropbox on my fresh 12.04 LTS installation and under "Preferences" I have checked "Start Dropbox on System Startup".

Under "Startup Applications" I can see Dropbox is listed with the command "dropbox start -i".

However, when starting my laptop Dropbox is not started until I manually run the command "~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd" in Terminal.

Why doesn't Dropbox start on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the startup application command to -

`sh -c  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

instead of `dropbox start -i`.

Since you are able to start it with the command, it should work.